# representing negative outputs dynamically in Taylor series expansion --> C++

Tags: c++, c++11, math, taylor-series

I am learning to code, so please forgive me for asking such a rudimentary question (gotta start somewhere, right?)  I have written the following C++ program which approximates an e^x series expansion (Taylor series).

The problem I have is with the output.  One of the sample outputs I need to have is as follows:

Sample Run 5:

This program approximates e^x using an n-term series expansion. 
Enter the number of terms to be used in the approximation of e^x-> 8 
Enter the exponent(x)-> -0.25

e^-0.25000 = 1.00000 - 0.25000 + 0.03125 - 0.00260 + 0.00016 - 0.00001 + 0.00000 - 0.00000 = 0.77880

But my code creates the following output instead:

e^-0.25000 = 1.00000 + -0.25000 + 0.03125 + -0.00260 + 0.00016 + -0.00001 + 0.00000 + -0.00000 = 0.77880

Essentially, I am unsure how to represent these negative values dynamically, in order to match the desired output. At present, they are all represented by " + " string literals in my code, in between the recursive term that repeats.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int numTerms, i;
long double x, numer, denom, prevDenom, term, sum;

int main ()
{
    cout << "This program approximates e^x using an n-term series expansion." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of terms to be used in the approximation of e^x-> ";
    cin >> numTerms;
    cout << "Enter the exponent(x)-> ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;

        if (numTerms <= 0)
            cout << numer << " is an invalid number of terms." << endl;
        else if (numTerms == 1)
        {
            sum = 1.00000;
            cout << "e^" << fixed << setprecision(5) << x << " = " << sum << " = " << sum << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "e^" << fixed << setprecision(5) << x <<" = " << 1.00000;
            sum += 1.00000;
            prevDenom = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < numTerms; i++)
            {
                numer = pow(x,(i));
                denom = (prevDenom) * (i);

                term = numer / denom;

                sum += term;
                prevDenom = denom;
                cout << " + " << term;
            }
            cout << " = " << fixed << setprecision(5) << sum << endl;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question boils down to how to write the value `-1` as `- 1` and the value `1` as `+ 1`. You should have reduced your code accordingly first. Now, the simple answer is to check the sign and either output `+` and `x` or `-` and `-x`.

Comment: Hello, and thanks!  Good point about simplifying my code; I hope to eventually get to the point where I do this automatically while I'm writing a program.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not about doing that when writing a program but when looking for a problem. Also, it's part of the rules here on stackoverflow that if you have a problem, you first reduce it to the smallest possible code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace:

```
cout << " + " << term;
```

with:

```
if (term >= 0)
    cout << " + " << term;
else
    cout << " - " << (-term);
```

So when a term is negative you print the minus sign yourself with the extra space you need and then you print the positive part of your term.

Comment: That will print `- 0` if the term is zero.